# Render joomla component inside same view

Tags: php, joomla, render

So i'm working with com_content component view,
and i need to load related items related to 
the one that's beeing viewed.
Is it possible to do that?

This is what i have so far:

```
$com = JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_content';

if (!class_exists('ContentController')) require($com.DS.'controller.php');
$config['base_path'] = $com;
$cont = new ContentController($config);

JRequest::setVar('view', 'categories');

$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_content', JPATH_SITE);

$cont->display();
```

I don't know if this is exactly how its supposed to be, but wait for any help if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, for anyone in my situation:

```
// Path to wanted component
$com = JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_content';

// Include controller, if its not already include
if (!class_exists('ContentController')) require($com.DS.'controller.php');

//  Inform controller of its base path
$config['base_path'] = $com;
// Init controller 
$cont = new ContentController($config);

// Get wanted view
$view =& $cont->getView('category', 'html');
// Add path to wanted template
$view->addTemplatePath(JPATH_SITE.DS.'templates'.DS.'ja_wall'.DS.'html'.DS.'com_content'.DS.'category');

 // Adding needed params to load info
JRequest::setVar('view', 'category');
JRequest::setVar('layout', 'blog');
JRequest::setVar('Itemid', '102');
JRequest::setVar('id', $this->item->catid);

 // Get and load language
$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_content', JPATH_SITE);

// Render page
$cont->display();
```